# Search pdf and extract page when found

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

Does anyone know how to search through a multiple page pdf for some text (e.g., an invoice number) and then extract that page to a separate file? I see how I can use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) to extract a particular page and then use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to modify and save. The part I can't figure out is how to search the pdf and determine the page number that text is on. This would preferably be done with php, but I'd be willing to use something else if necessary.

Are there any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page helped me find a solution:

http://www.freak-search.com/en/thread/2817957/find_page_number_containing_a_given_text

Basically, you use the command line program "pdftotext" in a bash script (see the link) to return the page number and then FPDI to extract the page. Works great.